# $I(u) = \int_{\Omega} |\nabla u|^p \mathrm{d}x$ is convex for $p > 2$?

Tags: analysis, convex-analysis

Let $p > 2$ and $I: W^{1,p}_0(\Omega) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a functional given by
$$I(u) = \dfrac{1}{p}\int_{\Omega} |\nabla u|^p \, \mathrm{d}x.$$
Is it possible to show that it is convex? In other words, for all $u,v \in W^{1,p}_0(\Omega)$ and $t \in [0,1]$, the inequality holds
$$I(tu + (1-t)v) \leq tI(u) + (1-t)I(v)?$$

Note: If an arbitrary functional $J$ is convex, then the map
$$u \mapsto \dfrac{1}{p}\int_{\Omega} J(u) \, \mathrm{d}x$$
will be too. In this way, I sought to verify that the auxiliary functional $J: W^{1,p}_0(\Omega) \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $J(u) = |\nabla u|^p$ is convex . The problem is that I only know inequalities like $|a + b|^p \leq 2^{p-1}(|a|^p + |b|^p)$ which didn't help me much.

Comment: Hint: let $f(x)=x^p$. Then $f''(x)>0$ for $p>2$.

Comment: It's much easier than it seems. Thanks! @xpaul

Comment: You are welcome!